# Recyclerview is not displaying even after visibility is VISIBLE

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making bus booking app. I created several layout for seat booking. Every layout working perfect with almost same code. But have problem in 1 layout only. Every layout have Lower and Upper deck. And i used Radio Buttons to switch view of upper and lower deck. But when i click on upper deck it is not showing upper deck.

**SeatSelection**

```
public class SeatSelectionSeatSleep3 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

RecyclerView recyclerLowerLeft;
RecyclerView recyclerLowerRight1;
RecyclerView recyclerLowerRight2;
RecyclerView recyclerUpper;
SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterLowerLeft seatAdapterLowerLeft;
SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterLowerRight1 seatAdapterLowerRight1;
SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterLowerRight2 seatAdapterLowerRight2;
SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterUpper seatAdapterUpper;
List<SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails> seatDetailsListLowerLeft;
List<SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails> seatDetailsListLowerRight1;
List<SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails> seatDetailsListLowerRight2;
List<SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails> seatDetailsListUpper;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerLowerLeft;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerLowerRight1;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerLowerRight2;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerUpper;
List seatNo;
List seatAvl;
TextView txtSeatNo;
TextView fare;
public Bitmap seatIcon;
public Bitmap seatSelect;
public Bitmap seatBooked;
public Bitmap sleepIcon;
public Bitmap sleepSelect;
public Bitmap sleepBooked;
String cost;
int amt;
int charge;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seat_selection_seat_sleep3);

    seatNo = new ArrayList();
    seatAvl = new ArrayList();


    amt = Integer.parseInt(cost);
    charge = 0;

    Button btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    fare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fare);
    txtSeatNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSeatNo);

    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.busDeckSelectionButtons);
    RadioButton rdoLower = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lowerDeck);
    RadioButton rdoUpper = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.upperDeck);

    final LinearLayout driver = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.driver);

    seatIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.seater_available);
    seatSelect = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.seater_selected);
    seatBooked = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.seater_booked);

    sleepIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.sleeping_available);
    sleepSelect = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.sleeper_select);
    sleepBooked = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.sleeper_booked);

    recyclerLowerLeft = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerLowerLeft);
    recyclerLowerRight1 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerLowerRight1);
    recyclerLowerRight2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerLowerRight2);
    recyclerUpper = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerupper);

    layoutManagerLowerLeft = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
    layoutManagerLowerRight1 = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
    layoutManagerLowerRight2 = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
    layoutManagerUpper = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);

    recyclerLowerLeft.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerLowerLeft);
    recyclerLowerRight1.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerLowerRight1);
    recyclerLowerRight2.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerLowerRight2);
    seatAdapterLowerLeft = new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterLowerLeft(this, loadSeatListLowerLeft());
    seatAdapterLowerRight1 = new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterLowerRight1(this, loadSeatListLowerRight1());
    seatAdapterLowerRight2 = new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterLowerRight2(this, loadSeatListLowerRight2());
    recyclerLowerLeft.setAdapter(seatAdapterLowerLeft);
    recyclerLowerRight1.setAdapter(seatAdapterLowerRight1);
    recyclerLowerRight2.setAdapter(seatAdapterLowerRight2);

    recyclerLowerLeft.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerLowerRight1.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerLowerRight2.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerUpper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);



    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.lowerDeck:
                    recyclerLowerLeft.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerLowerLeft);
                    recyclerLowerRight1.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerLowerRight1);
                    recyclerLowerRight2.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerLowerRight2);
                    seatAdapterLowerLeft = new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterLowerLeft(SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.this, loadSeatListLowerLeft());
                    seatAdapterLowerRight1 = new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterLowerRight1(SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.this, loadSeatListLowerRight1());
                    seatAdapterLowerRight2 = new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterLowerRight2(SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.this, loadSeatListLowerRight2());
                    recyclerLowerLeft.setAdapter(seatAdapterLowerLeft);
                    recyclerLowerRight1.setAdapter(seatAdapterLowerRight1);
                    recyclerLowerRight2.setAdapter(seatAdapterLowerRight2);
                    driver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recyclerLowerLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recyclerLowerRight1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recyclerLowerRight2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recyclerUpper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case R.id.upperDeck:
                    recyclerUpper.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerUpper);
                    seatAdapterUpper = new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterUpper(SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.this, loadBustListSeatsUpper());
                    recyclerUpper.setAdapter(seatAdapterUpper);
                    recyclerUpper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    driver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerLowerLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerLowerRight1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerLowerRight2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

public class SeatDetails {
    String name;
    boolean isBlank;
    boolean isSelected;

    public SeatDetails(String name, boolean isBlank, boolean isSelected) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isBlank = isBlank;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

}



public List<SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails> loadBustListSeatsUpper() {

    seatDetailsListUpper = new ArrayList<SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        if (isBlankSeatUpper(i)) {
            seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("", true, false));
        } else {
            if (i == 0) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU1", false, false));
            }   else if (i == 2) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU2",false, false));
            }  else if (i == 3) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU3",false, false));
            } else if (i == 4) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU4",false, false));
            } else if (i == 6) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU5",false, false));
            }  else if (i == 7) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU6",false, false));
            } else if (i == 8) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU7",false, false));
            } else if (i == 10) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU8",false, false));
            } else if (i == 11) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU9",false, false));
            } else if (i == 12) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU10",false, false));
            } else if (i == 14) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU11",false, false));
            } else if (i == 15) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU12",false, false));
            } else if (i == 16) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU13",false, false));
            }  else if (i == 18) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU14",false, false));
            }  else if (i == 19) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU15",false, false));
            } else if (i == 20) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU16",false, false));
            }else if (i == 22) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU17",false, false));
            }else if (i == 23) {
                seatDetailsListUpper.add(new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails("SU18",false, false));
            }
        }
    }
    return seatDetailsListUpper;
}


public boolean isBlankSeatUpper(int i) {
    if (i == 1)
        return true;
    if (i == 5)
        return true;
    if (i == 9)
        return true;
    if (i == 13)
        return true;
    if (i == 17)
        return true;
    if (i == 21)
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}

public class SeatAdapterUpper extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    class ViewHolderOriginal extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        ViewHolderOriginal(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

        }
    }


    class ViewHolderBlank extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ViewHolderBlank(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }
    }



    public Context cntx;
    public SeatAdapterUpper(Context context, List<SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails> list){
        this.cntx = context;
        seatDetailsListUpper = list;
    }

    // 0= Original view 1= Blank View
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (position == 1)
            return 1;
        if (position == 5)
            return 1;
        if (position == 9)
            return 1;
        if (position == 13)
            return 1;
        if (position == 17)
            return 1;
        if (position == 21)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (viewType == 1)
            return new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterUpper.ViewHolderBlank(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_blank, parent, false));
        else
            return new SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterUpper.ViewHolderOriginal(inflater.inflate(R.layout.seatrow_grid_sleep, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (holder instanceof SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterUpper.ViewHolderBlank) {

        } else if
                (holder instanceof SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterUpper.ViewHolderOriginal) {
            SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails seatDetails = seatDetailsListUpper.get(position);

            if (seatNo.contains(seatDetails.getName())) {
                ((SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterUpper.ViewHolderOriginal) holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(sleepSelect);
            } else if (seatAvl.contains(seatDetails.getName())) {
                ((SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterUpper.ViewHolderOriginal) holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(sleepIcon);
            } else {
                ((SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatAdapterUpper.ViewHolderOriginal) holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(sleepBooked);
            }

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SeatSelectionSeatSleep3.SeatDetails seatDetails = seatDetailsListUpper.get(position);

                    if (seatNo.contains(seatDetails.getName())) {
                        seatDeselectedUpper(position);
                    } else if (seatAvl.contains(seatDetails.getName())) {
                        seatSelectedUpper(position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return seatDetailsListUpper.size();
    }
}
}
```

Added code related to Upper Deck only. Removed Lower deck adapters. Lower deck working fine when i click back on Lower. But problem is with only Upper Deck.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to remove the business logic from your code, so its just focusing on rendering the UI elements only. This way it will be easier to debug. Also include any errors reported

Comment: No there is no error. And all code i posted all r related to that. Which include Radio Buttons and Recycler Adapter. @NitinSingh

Answer (score 1):

To answer this is very hard as your code is a little confusing to look at, you need to remove some of your business logic and just include the code that effects the issue at hand.

I would highly recommend to read a book called: [Clean Code by Robert C. Martin](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) to improve your coding abilities. And for Android specifically I would recommend looking at [this page](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices). By cleaning your code and making it more modular and ordered, you'll be better equipped to debug and solve this problem yourself.